# App.route is not a function when accessing it in a controller function for express routing

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to create a simple API using NodeJS.

I plan to separate the main `api.js`, `route-definitions.js`, `route-logic.js` in their own separate folders for them to be more structured and organized.

However, when I call `app.route()` in my `route-definitions.js`, it fails at compilation and saying that `app.route` is not a function.

**server.js**

```
  var express = require('express')
  var api = require("./api/api.js");

  app = express();
  port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
  app.use('/', api);

  app.listen(port);
```

**api.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use('/read', require('./routes/route-definitions'));

module.exports = router;
```

**route-definitions.js**

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {

  var operations = require('../controllers/route-logic.js')

  //Route to check if a file with the same file name already exists
  app.route('/getItems')
    .post(operations.getItems);
}
```

When I try to run the API locally, and call /read/getItems, I get the error:

> TypeError: app.route is not a function

What am I missing? I'm fairly new to Node and Express, but I know I'm not passing the app instance correctly or it is not set globally.

Comment: as you need we create demo for you. please download and check.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yshh2hej0y0j70k/CRUD%20Demo.zip?dl=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it by creating a child router in **route-definitions.js**

```
var router = require('express').Router();
var operations = require('../controllers/route-logic.js');

router.post('/getItems', operations.getItems);

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried adding another router in the route-definitions.js but still got the same error with `app.route is not a function`.

Comment: @KawamotoTakeshi My apologies, I have updated the answer. I assume that `operations.getItems` is a function that accepts request and response, is it correct?

Comment: Your assumption is correct! I also tried the change you've made and it works perfectly! Thank you so much!

Comment: @KawamotoTakeshi Glad to hear that it worked. You are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In api.js you need to pass the router to the function you are exporting in route-definitions.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.use('/read', require('./routes/route-definitions')(router));

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestion and got the error: `TypeError: Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You've used `app` in the `route-definitions.js` but looks like you forgot to pass it to that module.

Please have a look at below code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var app = express();
router.use('/read', require('./routes/route-definitions')(app));
module.exports = router;
```